# specify array key value in string

Tags: arrays, string

```
$row[4] = "comes from database" - pincode eg. 364001 
$code=$row[4];
$array=array("State Name"=>$row[1] , "District" => $row[2] , "Assembly" => $row[3], "Code" => $code);
```

Convert `$code` into string

means

"code"=> "$code"

but give error

so that 364001 become as a string not number

How to do this?

Comment: "code" = "$code" so that becomes like "364001" in string format

Comment: There is no reason to change var type, but if you need it, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change variable type from integer to string is possible using `(string)` before variable name.

```
$int = 12345;
var_dump($int); // int(12345)

$str = (string)$int;
var_dump($str); // string(5) "12345"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want another option, you can use the `trim` function as follows:

```
trim($code,""");
```